# Using custom CSS when there is no div ID

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm running a website on Wordpress. Whenever I have to do CSS, I go onto Appearance > Custom CSS. To find the element I want to target I use the Inspect tool.

However on this instance there is no element ID. As this a small browser window for allowing card payment, I cannot find the div ID using Inspector.

IMAGES

[Not OK to CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RmCZ.png)

[OK to CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgH06.png)

Comment: You could style by using the class, so .elementor-heading-title { ... }, but keep in mind these styles will apply to all elements with the class .elementor-heading-title. You could restrict to only h2's with this class by doing h2.elementor-heading-title { ... } too, but it gets tricky if you can't add an id to the element. Note: this isn't the cleanest way because you're adding the styles to an existing class and it might not make sense to do.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to give the [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) documentation a read. There are many ways to select an element without a distinct Class or ID, including by [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors), and even [Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators) (which are probably the best way to solve this problem you're having).

- You can start be selecting an ancestor of the element you want, such as the`.woocommerce` wrapper.
- You could then use the [Direct Child Combinator: `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and select the `.order_details` element.
- Now you can use the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator: `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to select the `div` that *is its adjacent sibling*.

> (Note that the **adjacent sibling combinator** is used here, not the [General Sibling Combinator: `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), otherwise it would select all `divs` that are a later sibling of `.order_details`.

The following selector would probably be more than sufficient, and perhaps even a bit more specific than it needs to be (you *may not* need the `>`, but I put it in there for good measure - when using combinators on elements with no id or class, adding another layer of specificity usually doesn't hurt)

```
.woocommerce > .order_details + div { /* Styles here*/ }
```

If you're trying to override any of the inline styles on that div, you'll need to be more careful about the [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector. Generally speaking there are 4 levels of specificity:

```
inline - ID - class - element
```

The Selector I gave you above has a specificity of `0021` (no inline, no ID, 2 classes, 1 element). However after your comment, it looks like you're trying to overwrite an inline style which has a gargantuan specificity of `1000`. So if you apply any CSS that's not already defined inline, it should handily take effect. If you're changing any of the inline styles themselves, you'll need to make use of the _generally, but not always, bad-practice: [**`!important` Exception**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception). Using `!important` will actually add a fifth order of magnitude to your specificity:

```
!important - inline - ID - class - element
```

So, if you're trying to change your inline background color, using the following:

```
.woocommerce > .order_details + div { background-color: #0095ee !important; }
```

Will give your blue background color an astounding `10021` specificity, which is higher than the inline grey's `01000`.

> Be very careful not to overuse `!important` - it's a tool that should be reserved for situations like this, and not just because you have a few CSS rules above that are slightly more specific.

Here's a [handy CSS Specificity](https://cssspecificity.com/) list, and a [handy CSS Specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your quick reply Xhynk, however the suggested method did not work.

The following code yields not change:

.woocommerce > .order_details + div {background-color:black }

or 

.woocommerce-notices-wrapper > .order_details + div {background-color:black }

Could you kindly assist?

Comment: The last one ( with `.woocommerce-notices-wrapper > ` is wrong, since `.order_details` is not a child of it, you'd need `.woocommerce-notices-wrapper +`. That said, you'll need to look at your [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) since you're changing styles that were declared inline. I've updated the answer, but basically you'll (most likely) need to add `background-color: black !important;` since those attributes have a specificity of `1000` which is difficult to override without some horribly ugly specific selectors.

Comment: Glad to help! Do heed the warning that `!important` should only be used in situations like the above - future you thanks you! 